# Typeorm connection to postgres

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, typeorm, serverless

I'am trying to connect typeorm to postgresql on serverless framework but i'm getting error.

"message": "No repository for "Blog" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?"
}

ormconfig

```
export class Database {
  
  private static connection: Connection

  public getConnection = async () => {

    if (!Database.connection) {
      Database.connection = await createConnection({
        name: 'default',
        type: 'postgres',
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        port: 5432,
        username: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_NAME,
        entities: [
          'src/entities/*.ts',
        ],
        migrations: [
          "src/migrations/*.ts"
        ],
        cli: {
          entitiesDir: "src/entities",
          migrationsDir: "src/migrations",
        },
        synchronize: true,
        logging: false
      })
    }
  }
}
```

blog entity

```
import {BaseEntity, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class Blog extends BaseEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: true })
    public name: string;
  
    @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: true })
    public description: string;
  
    @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: true })
    public author: string;
  
    @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: true })
    public image: string;
  
    @Column({ type: 'timestamp', nullable: true })
    public created_at: Date;

}
```

lambda

```
export const main = middyfy(async (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {

  const db = new Database();
    db.getConnection();
    
  try {
    const blog = new Blog();
    blog.name = "Timber";
    blog.description = "Testing";
    await blog.save();

    return formatJSONResponse({
      blog
    })

 }catch (e) {
    return formatJSONResponse({
        status: 500,
        message: e
    });
 }
})
```

I'm new in this and just trying to connect it i created migration and model blog now i want to save data to it.
whats i'm doing wrong can someone please help me )